# Review Stats page takes 5 seconds to load

Tags: bug

This isn't a very big deal, but I've noticed that the "Review Stats" pages take approximately 5 seconds to load, regardless of review type. According to Firebug, about 4.75 seconds of the request is spent "Waiting" (which means the server is processing ASP). For example, try viewing the [Suggested Edits Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats).

My guess is that these pages didn't always take this long to load, so this is likely caused by the SQL query behind the page. My first 2 thoughts I are that either a table that isn't indexed properly or the SQL query could be refined.

Comment: That's because the query for those pages is rather heavy on the servers, given Stack Overflow's dataset....

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sure it's heavy, but I wouldn't think it'd be that heavy. Sure it's joining at least 2 tables with probably about 10 million rows, but with proper `JOIN`ing, `COUNT`ing, and `GROUP`ing I'm sure it would run in under 5 seconds, especially on [SO's hardware](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/).